# system library:connect:No route to host

Tags: sockets, networking, routes, openssl, connection

I have a small sample application which send some data to the server and close the connection afterwards. I ran it on my *localhost as server & client* and it **worked**.

When I ran the *same code* after *changing the IP to another host*(running Cent OS in VM) as server and my client (Ubuntu), I get the following **error from client binary**.

```
client.c : 47 Error connection to remote machine  
139915881411416:error:02002071:system library:connect:No route to host:bss_conn.c:246:host=192.168.56.101:6001
139915881411416:error:20073067:BIO routines:CONN_STATE:connect error:bss_conn.c:249:
```

I am able to ping the remote server from my terminal. Any suggestions or solutions are welcome :) .

Comment: No route to host is a basic socket error that means that there is no way to connect to that IP address "192.168.56.101" from the machine that runs the client.

Comment: i.e. there is nothing C related in this question. You could try to telnet, netcat or something like that to 192.168.56.101:6001, and get the same error.

Comment: May be you need to check firewall rules on the server.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the *problem* was because of **firewall running on server(Cent OS)**. After **stopping the firewal**l using command,

```
service iptables stop
```

the client was able to make a connection with the server.

**Better Solution (without stopping firewall):**

*Add* your *client's IP address* in the *iptable*s so that it will allow the client to connect to your server without stopping firewall.

```
iptables -I INPUT -s <client_ip_address> -j ACCEPT
```